# Extracting IP address from cron not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I have a script and I am running it as scheduled via cron. In that script I have line to extract IP address of that machine and that line is below

```
ip_address=$(ip addr show | grep -E -o '(inet ([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}))' | grep -v 'inet 127.0.0.1' |
sed 's/inet//g')
```

If I am just executing above line on bash command line its working and `echo $ip_address` giving me IP of that machine but If I am calling it via crobjob , `echo $ip_address` giving empty output.

even If I call entire script from bash shell, I am getting IP in the output but only via cron I am not getting the IP in the output.

Could someone please help ?

Thank you.

Comment: `ip` is in `/sbin` which is usually not in default `PATH`. The usual `PATH` when running via cron is `/usr/bin:/bin`.

Comment: oh so you mean I should place like /sbin/ip ?

Comment: Yes, that's what you should do.

Comment: I will update you Thank you very much

Comment: You can shorten your code to `ip_address=$(/sbin/ip -f inet -o addr show dev eth0 | sed 's/^.*inet[^1-2]*//;s|/.*||')`. Assuming your interface is `eth0`.

Comment: It can be further shorten by `ip addr show eth0| grep -oP 'inet \K[^/]+'` or just `hostname -i` or `hostname -I`

Comment: My script can extract all interfaces IP address but yes your answers are also good, short and simple. Thank you very much everyone